# createHidden() and createTextBox() issue with behavior of encoding of string in .setValue() and .setText()

Tags: google-apps-script

I found what I believe is a problem with `createHidden().setValue()`.
I am using a hidden box to pass information to handler functions. When there is a & in the string an encoding is done while not expected - by me.

```
var test = '[[12060,"Crédit R&D à recevoir"]]';
var hidden = app.createHidden().setId('z').setName('z').setValue(test);
```

When I read the data back it's

```
[[12060,&quot;Crédit R&amp;D à recevoir&quot;]]
```

It's basically causing problems later on with `Utilities.jsonParse()`.

Now without the &

```
var test = '[[12060,"Crédit RD à recevoir"]]';
var hidden = app.createHidden().setId('z').setName('z').setValue(test);
```

When I read the data back it's what I am expecting - meaning no encoding:

```
[[12060,"Crédit RD à recevoir"]]
```

Now if I do the same with `app.createTextBox().setText(test);` I do not have any encoding causing a problem even with the &. I will get back `[[12060,"Crédit R&D à recevoir"]]` with the & not encoded.

Is this a bug or a feature/behavior I am not aware of for the `createHidden.setValue()`?

Thanks if somebody can clarify for me this mystery that made me loose a good hour!

**UPDATE** : I reported the issue to Google and it's officially a bug - see [issue 1576](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1576).

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid but I thought that the value set to hidden had to be  string... is it supposed to work as you show ?

Comment: Correct, and i am passing a string. In my application I use `Utilities.jsonStringify()` on an Array. But it's not the issue here. I am passing a string and it's encoded while I believe it should not. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google accepted the issue as a new bug to be fixed - see [issue 1576](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1576).
So in the meantime, we should use `createTextBox().setText()` which do not have the HTML encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Issue 1115](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1115). It says it was fixed in March this year. You can report your findings there

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same issue but for the `createHidden().setValue()` function instead of the listbox. Should I create a new bug entry rather than happend to a the issue 1115?

Comment: I think you should do both because 1115 is now closed. Add a note to 1115 saying the problem still exists in hidden fields and open a new bug and reference each other

Comment: Thanks. I created a new [Issue 1576](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1576).